# Why is my css after the first ruleset not being applied?

Tags: html, css

For the past few days I have been experiencing a mysterious problem. I have defined some css, and after the first ruleset it is not being applied. So I wrote some basic css here to see if there still is a problem, and there was. Is there a simple mistake I have been making?

style.css

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, lightblue, white);
};

th {
  text-align: left;
};
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Toothbrush</td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shaving Cream</td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: no `;` after `}`

Comment: oops, I guess that became a habit! thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do not use ; in your CSS after the closing }.